# After updating AFNetworking to 4.0 in pod file. Facing problem in implementation of AFOAuth2Manager and AFNetworkActivityLogger

Tags: uiwebview, afnetworking, wkwebview, afoauth2manager

After updating pod to AFNetworking 4.0, I noticed that AFOAuth2Manager and AFNetworkActivityLogger are not available with this release.

I am using authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString() method to perform a login task in my application.
Also, AFNetworkActivityLogger is being used as AFNetworkActivityLogger.shared().startLogging().

Can anyone please suggest a way to use AFOAuth2Manager and AFNetworkActivityLogger with an updated AFNetworking framework.
OR
Please let me know an alternative to handle this scenario.